# IVParameter Spec Problem in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I am currently devloping a Windows application using C# and looking at developing a mobile app using Java.

The windows software and the mobile app will work together, the windows app will store information and encrypt certain information before storing it in an online database.

The mobile app will pull the information from the online database and will need to decrypt the encrypted string that is retrieved from the datbase.

The encryption method I am using in C# is below

```
        byte[] clearTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptionString);

        SymmetricAlgorithm rijn = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] rgbIV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ryojvlzmdalyglrj");

        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo");
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijn.CreateEncryptor(key, rgbIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cs.Write(clearTextBytes, 0, clearTextBytes.Length);

        cs.Close();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

The Windows method works fine.

The code I am using in Java is as follows:

```
KeySpec ks = new DESKeySpec("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(ks);

        String ivString = "ryojvlzmdalyglrj";
        byte[] ivByte = ivString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
        //RC5ParameterSpec iv = new RC5ParameterSpec(ivByte);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        byte[] encoded = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64("iNtaFme3B/e6DppNSp9QLg=="));

        Log.d("Decoded Password", encoded.toString());
```

As both methods need to encrypt and decrypt the same string together it has to use the same key and IV. The only problem that I am having is in the java method the IVParameterSpec is going into the catch with an error that says IV must be 8 bytes long.

How can I resolve this to ensure that I have the same IV as C#.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are encrypting (in C#) with AES (also known as Rjindael), but trying to decrypt in Java with DES. If you change your Java code to use AES then it should all work fine.

DES uses an 8-byte IV because it works on 64-bit blocks. AES uses a 16-byte IV because it works on 128-bit blocks.

You should also make sure you use the same character encoding. In C# you are using ASCII, but in java you're using UTF-8. In your case they will be the same, but you should really fix it now to prevent strange bugs in future. You can change the character set name in Java to "US-ASCII" and it'll work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. When I change the first SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES).... and replace the the DES with AES it comes up with an error that says SecretKeyFactory AES implementation not found

Comment: I recommend using the BouncyCastle (http://www.bouncycastle.org) lightweight API instead of the Java JCE. JCE is full of problems like that.

Comment: Use a SecretKeySpec instead. But I do agree with @Cameron Skinner.

Comment: OK, I have changed it to SecretKeySpec like SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("hcxilkqbbhczfeultgbskdmaunivmfuo".getBytes("US-ASCII"), "AES"); but I still get the same IV error 'IV must be 8 bytes long

Comment: I forgot to mention in the previous comment the code I am using for the IV is IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("ryojvlzmdalyglrj".getBytes("US_ASCII"));

Comment: Have you changed the `Cipher.getInstance` call to "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same algorithm of course. The default algorithm is for .NET is AES, so that is what you should be using on the Java side as well.